# Can I add a widget to the padding space?

Tags: flutter

How can I add a widget to the padding space?

I'm trying to make a button like this picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZKi.png

The reason for making this button is to keep the maximum size as the button does not affect the size of the container, and the button is additional UI with and without buttons.

Is it possible? If not, please give me some advice and tips.

Comment: you can put container in to row and keep container as children, you can add any widget before keep container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stack

```
      Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'X',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

or try with row

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children [
        button()
        container()
        sizebox()
        ]
```